# To whom should I request a recommendation letters if I am currently employed but applying to a different university?

Tags: recommendation-letter, job

I'm 5 years into my current position. But really want to leave. I'm planning to apply to 6 positions this year. I lost contact with my "official" letter writers (postdoc boss, PhD advisor) and don't think they can reflect on what I have been doing since I was hired. I was wondering if I should ask for recommendation letters from my colleagues or perhaps even my chair and dean. At the same time, I don't want to share with them the fact that I want to leave. What to do?

Comment: Are you on a tenure track? Are you at risk of not gaining tenure?

Comment: Collaborators or coauthors? Even after 5 years I'd hope your previous letter writers would still have something to say.